# How do I add/update a list of ingredients to an instance of class Recipes in Grails?

Tags: grails, grails-orm

I will try to be as succinct as possible, I am completely new to Grails and in my class we are working on developing an app that will collect recipes in a DB. To do this we need a new recipe form that will collect the basics (name, course, dietary category, prep. time, etc.) upon submission of that form, the user is taken to another page “Update ingredients”, that lists the current ingredients, and allows a user to remove or add new ingredients (via a text field). Every time the user adds an ingredient, it should update the list of current ingredients.

```
class RecipesController {


def addIngredients () {
    def i = Recipes.get(params.id)
    i.properties = params
    [ingredients:i]
    i.save()
    redirect (action:"index")
```

Above is just the actions related to the addIngredients view, as the rest of my app works so far I will only post that code if necessary.

```
<g:if test="${ingredients.empty}">
<g:textField name="ingredient" />
</g:if>

<g:else>
<g:each var="item" in="${ingredients}">
    ${item.ingredients}
    <g:textField name="ingredient"/>
</g:each>
</g:else>

<g:submitButton name="Submit"/>
```

At this point I have been tinkering around for hours so my code is probably pretty FUBAR. Please let me know if any further code or explanation is needed. Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: Run `grails generate-all my.app.Recipes` and have a look at the generated controller. This will give you a good idea how save/update works.

Comment: its not clear what your problem is... how is it currently NOT working, what are you getting and how is it different to what you expect it to do?

Comment: sorry, currently I get an error "cannot set property 'ingredients' on null object after submitting the first form and redirecting to my "addIngredients" view. I expected to be able to successfully display this view, collect ingredients in a text field and append that list to the corresponding instance of the Recipe class. Please let me know if you need anything more

Comment: @zoran119 is right - generate-all will give you a working example for the right way to do it and you can just borrow the code snippets you need. Your error though is essentially just a Null pointer so make sure your objects are getting initialized correctly.

Comment: cool thanks, I will look for how to run that in IDEA or what I will need to do to run it because I couldn't get it last night although at that point I was exhausted so I probably missed something